# Javascript injection add item to basket

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am trying to run this script which effectively goes through a json list that contains url and a size to go to the link set add the item to cart based on size, check if it is in stock or already added. I have got the link and the size searching algorithms work independently but together they seem to not work and I can't figure out why?

```
var foundall = false;
var copItems = [{
  "url": "https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/#products/303518/22745",
  "size": "Medium"
}];
for (var i = 0; i < copItems.length; i++) {
  AddToCart(copItems[i], function(carted) {
    console.log(carted);
  });
}

function AddToCart(item, callback) {
  location.href = item.url;
  var counter = 0;
  var waitToAppear = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.querySelector('#cart-update > span')) {
      if (document.querySelector('#cart-update > span').innerHTML == 'remove') {
        return callback("failed");
        clearInterval(waitToAppear);
      } else if (document.querySelector('#cart-update > span').innerHTML == 'sold out') {
        copSelectSize(size, function(data) {
          return callback(data);
          clearInterval(waitToAppear);
        });
      } else if (document.querySelector('#cart-update > span').innerHTML == 'add to basket') {
        copSelectSize(item.size, function(Sized) {
          return callback("failed");
          clearInterval(waitToAppear);
        })
      } else {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter == 5) {
          return callback("failed");
          clearInterval(waitToAppear);
        }
      }
    }
  }, 100);
}

function copSelectSize(size, callback) {
  var counter = 0;
  var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('size-options').length) {
      var sizes = document.getElementById('size-options').options;
      var size_id;
      for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        if (sizes[i].innerText == '\(Size)') {
          size_id = i;
          document.getElementById('size-options').selectedIndex = size_id;
          document.getElementById('size-options-link').innerHTML = '\(Size)';
          if (document.querySelector('#cart-update > span').innerHTML != 'remove') {
            document.querySelector('#cart-update > span').click();
            return callback("success");
            clearInterval(checkExist);
          }
          var checkExista = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.querySelector('#cart-update > span').innerHTML == 'remove') {
              checkExista = '';
            }
            clearInterval(checkExista);
          }, 100);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 5) {
      return callback("failed");
      clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting if any?

Comment: I am not getting any errors on running it, however it keeps logging "failed" and is not pressing add to cart.